# Fortran OOP post and pre-multiply

Tags: oop, generics, fortran, multiplication

I am implementint the vector-scalar multiplication. The scalar can be of type integer or type real. I must also allow multiplication of vector with scalar (v = u * scal) and the reverse (v = scal * u). The following code giver an error because it cannot distinguish between the two.
One solution would be to have four functions to take care of integer and real scalar types and for each have the post and pre-multiply operation. Does there exist a way to avoid having four functions and have only two?

This is to assign the Operator (*)

```
!> Multiplies a vector by a scalar such that one can write
!> v = scal * u and v = u * scal.
Procedure :: vector_scalar_postmultiply
Procedure, Pass (ub) :: vector_scalar_premultiply
Generic :: Operator (*) => vector_scalar_postmultiply, &
                           vector_scalar_premultiply
```

This is the post-multiply function

```
!> Multiplies a vector by a scalar such that one can write
!> v = scal * u and v = u * scal.
Procedure :: vector_scalar_postmultiply
Procedure, Pass (ub) :: vector_scalar_premultiply
Generic :: Operator (*) => vector_scalar_postmultiply, &
                     vector_scalar_premultiply

Function vector_scalar_postmultiply  &
(                                    &
  u,                                 & 
  scal                               &
)                                    &
  Result (v)

  !!$ In.
  Class (Vector), Intent(in) :: u
  Class (*), Intent(in) :: scal

  !!$ Out.
  Type (Vector) :: v

  Select Type (scal)

  !!$ scal points to integer intrinsic type. 
  Type Is (Integer)
    v% x = Real (scal) *  u% x
    v% y = Real (scal) *  u% y
    v% z = Real (scal) *  u% z

  !!$ scal points to real intrinsic type. 
  Type Is (Real)
    v% x = scal *  u% x
    v% y = scal *  u% y
    v% z = scal *  u% z

  End Select

End Function vector_scalar_postmultiply
```

This is the pre-multiply function

```
Function vector_scalar_premultiply  &
(                                   &
  scalb,                            & 
  ub                                &
)                                   &
  Result (vb)

  !!$ In.
  Class (*), Intent(in) :: scalb
  Class (Vector), Intent(in) :: ub

  !!$ Out.
  Type (Vector) :: vb

  Select Type (scalb)

  !!$ scal points to integer intrinsic type. 
  Type Is (Integer)
    vb% x = Real (scalb) *  ub% x
    vb% y = Real (scalb) *  ub% y
    vb% z = Real (scalb) *  ub% z

  !!$ scal points to real intrinsic type. 
  Type Is (Real)
    vb% x = scalb *  ub% x
    vb% y = scalb *  ub% y
    vb% z = scalb *  ub% z  

  End Select

End Function vector_scalar_premultiply
```

The error is the following

```
gfortran -o build/lib/foul.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/foul.f
gfortran -o build/lib/vectors.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/vectors.f
lib/vectors.f:214.28:

Generic :: Operator (*) => vector_scalar_postmultiply, &
                    1
Error: 'vector_scalar_postmultiply' and 'vector_scalar_premultiply' for GENERIC '*' 
at (1) are ambiguous

scons: *** [build/lib/vectors.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: What could be the right function if one tries to multiply two objects of class vector ? Both functions seem to authorize that !

Comment: Yes, that is one problem.

Comment: This is a euclidean vector. As you say I can use a rank-1 array for a vector, although I would have to restrain it to three components. Higher rank vectors will not be considered multi-dimensional arrays but Tensors. A rank-2 array will be a tensor of order two. Additionally the problem of pre and post operations are a common occurrance and would like to resolve them without using too many functions. I will go through your suggestion of creating a class scalar and what would be the implications.

Comment: Incidentally if I create Class(Scalar), I would still not be able to do v = u + 3 or v = u + 3.0

Comment: What do you have in mind exactly, and how would you code Class(Scalar)?

Comment: I wouldn't create Scalar either. I would say to code the long way for the various types. Currently I do not see a way to avoid conflicts when using Class(*)

Comment: The good thing about Class(Vector) is that it would allocate memory automatically. However the current vector class deals with euclidean forms for now. I also have the notion of components x, y, z.

Comment: Sure. The allocation would be done in the constructor so one does not have to call allocate when one use Class (vector). Discussion is good as I want to access other points of view.